# To add gradle Task for Serenity-JS for typescript

Tags: gradle, serenity-js

How to add a gradle task in build.gradle for serenity-js project? 
Please pointers to reference where we can get the sample implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of `serenity-js` but it seems to be a `nodejs` plugin. I'm guessing you could invoke this via [gradle-node-plugin](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin)